# Exporting Data from Data Table

Tags: angular, datatable

I'm trying to implement a data table in my project and it's all goods but when I'm trying to add exporting buttons such as excel, print, and pdf only the columns are showing. How to fix this guys? I used data table from this [Button Extension](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/extensions/buttons)

## Html

```
<table class="table table-striped" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
        <thead>
          <tr>a
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Tin</th>
            <th scope="col">Tax Payer Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Contact Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Business Address</th>
            <th scope="col">Date of Registration</th>
            <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center; width: 15%">Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngIf="allUsers?.length != 0">
          <tr *ngFor="let user of allUsers">
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">
                <i class="bi bi-pencil"></i>
              </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
              </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="bi bi-eye"></i>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody *ngIf="allUsers?.length == 0">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="7" class="no-data-available" style="text-align: center;">No matching records found</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

## Typescript

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'simple_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      autoWidth: false,
      // "scrollY": "543px",
      lengthMenu: [
        [ 10, 15, 20, -1 ],
        [ '10 rows', '15 rows', '20 rows', 'Show all' ]
    ],
    language: {
      buttons: {
          pageLength: {
              // _: "Show %d rows",
              '10': "10 rows",
              '15': "15 rows",
              '20': "20 rows",
              '-1': "All rows",
          }
      }
  },
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        {
          extend: 'pageLength',
          titleAttr: 'Filter Rows',
        },
        // {
        //   extend: 'spacer',
        // },
        {
          extend: 'copy',
          titleAttr: 'Filter Rows',
        },
        {
          extend: 'excelHtml5',
          text: '<i class="bi bi-file-earmark-excel"></i>',
          titleAttr: 'Excel',
          autoFilter: true,
        },
        {
          extend: 'print',
          text: '<i class="bi bi-printer"></i>',
          titleAttr: 'Print',
        },
        {
          extend: 'pdfHtml5',
          text: '<i class="bi bi-file-earmark-pdf"></i>',
          titleAttr: 'PDF',
        },
      ],
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback: ({}) => void) => {
        this.http
          .post<DataTablesResponse>('https://xtlncifojk.eu07.qoddiapp.com/',
            dataTablesParameters, {}
          )
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.allUsers = res.data;

            callback({
              recordsTotal: res.recordsTotal,
              recordsFiltered: res.recordsFiltered,
              data: [],
            });
          });
      },
      columns: [
      { data: 'id' },
      { data: 'firstName' },
      { data: 'lastName' },
      { data: 'contact' },
      { data: 'business' },
      { data: 'date' },
    ],
      select: true
    };
    return this.dtOptions;  
  }
```

Im getting like this [My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpzYJ.png)
i want Like this [Sample Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSuDo.png)